# After successful login IE alone not opening the page

Tags: php, internet-explorer, wampserver

I installed Booked software in wampserver and made necessary changes in config.php.

If I open the  index page and login, it's redirecting to dashboard.php, but the screen remains in index.php

All other browsers are redirecting to next page except IE.
I found the problem also.

If I remove localhost/Web from script.url settings and make it http:// then its working fine in IE.

If it's http: then
After submitting a reservation it fails to load the homepage instead it loads like this http://localhost/dashboard.php/localhost/dashboard.php which results to an error page.

My config.php

```
$conf['settings']['app.title'] = 'Booked Scheduler';    
$conf['settings']['default.timezone'] = 'America/Chicago';      
$conf['settings']['allow.self.registration'] = 'true';          
$conf['settings']['admin.email'] = 'admin@example.com';
$conf['settings']['admin.email.name'] = 'Booked Administrator'; 
$conf['settings']['default.page.size'] = '50';                  
$conf['settings']['enable.email'] = 'true';                  
$conf['settings']['default.language'] = 'en_us';                
$conf['settings']['script.url'] = '**http://localhost/Web';     
$conf['settings']['image.upload.directory'] = 'Web/uploads/images'; 
$conf['settings']['image.upload.url'] = 'uploads/images';       
$conf['settings']['cache.templates'] = 'true';                  
$conf['settings']['use.local.jquery'] = 'false';                
$conf['settings']['registration.captcha.enabled'] = 'true';
$conf['settings']['registration.require.email.activation'] = 'false';
$conf['settings']['registration.auto.subscribe.email'] = 'false';   
$conf['settings']['registration.notify.admin'] = 'false';
$conf['settings']['inactivity.timeout'] = '30';  
$conf['settings']['name.format'] = '{first} {last}';            
$conf['settings']['css.extension.file'] = '';                   
$conf['settings']['disable.password.reset'] = 'false';          
$conf['settings']['home.url'] = ''; 
$conf['settings']['logout.url'] = ''; 
$conf['settings']['default.homepage'] = '1';
```

Any suggestions to resolve this?

Note:Registration page is working perfectly in IE

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a Virtual Host to run this app in. See [this SO post for assistance in that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: I added the Virtual Host as per the steps, but still its not working in IE alone.

Comment: Have you replaced all the config items related to your new Virtual Hosts domain name